R: Transform a defined vector of replacements for str_replace_all() used in dplyr workflow into a dataframe to disply in nicely formated table
I have to work on a huge messy table, which is filled by users using a rudimentary Excel form. I know, it would be great to have this Excel with predefined select options, but that's not under my control. So I have to structure the mess.
I have written some R code to clean the data as for e.g. correct all typos entered to the data, do some descriptive stats and present it in Rmarkdown report each time I have a new version. Some basic corrections would be as such:
my_typo_corrections<- c(
   '\n'=''
  ,';$'=''
  ,';;'=';'
  ,'; ; '='; '
  ,'woodyland' = 'woodland'
  ,'what so ever' = 'whatever')
    
my_corrected_df <- my_df%>%
  dplyr::mutate(string_to_correct = str_replace_all(string_to_correct, my_typo_corrections))

Now I need to present all the typo corrections in a nicely formatted tables in the appendix of the report, such as:

Therefore, I need to get my vector my_typo_corrections into a data frame having the typos and the corrections in separate column such as:
         typos corrections
1           \n            
2           ;$            
3           ;;          ;;
4         ; ;         ; ; 
5    woodyland    woodland
6 what so ever    whatever

I struggle with how to separate the typo and the correction the vector. Also there are many escaped special characters. Any ideas?

data.frame(my_typo_corrections) |> rownames_to_column("typos")?

It's as easy as it can be! Thanks!

another option would be:
df <- cbind.data.frame(Typo=names(my_typo_corrections), Correction=my_typo_corrections) ; rownames(df) <- NULL
